# Determining when a Flow returns no data

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

The Kotlin flow states the following:

> A suspending function asynchronously returns a single value, but how
> can we return multiple asynchronously computed values? This is where
> Kotlin Flows come in.

However, if the source of my flow is such that when it completes but returns no data, is there a way to determine that from the flow? For example, if the source of the flow calls a backend API but the API returns no data, is there a way to determine when the flow completes and has no data?

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-empty.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can just do `toList()` on the flow and check if it's empty

Comment: You can, but it defeats the purpose of a flow. If the flow emits 1000 elements, it will collect all 1000 of them to a list instead of handling them one by one as they are emitted.

Comment: @SimonForsberg but to know if the flow was empty you have to collect it anyway. That's kinda the requirement to even start checking if it was empty or now.. And in the question there is a requirement "when the flow completes". The whole question is about calling api, so i can safely assume we're not talking about 1000 elements. Either way - in this context collecting the flow should be just fine

Comment: The flow needs to be collected by calling `.collect` on it, yes. (Or another terminal function). But flows are _asynchronous_. Collecting the entire flow to a list removes the asynchronousity (unless you are using `.onEach` possibly) and leads to a lot higher memory consumption than required. `flow.count()` only uses one value and is significantly cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

If the API returns a `Flow`, it is usually expected to return 0 or more elements. That flow will typically be collected by some piece of code in order to process the values. The `collect()` call is a suspending function, and will return when the flow completes:

```kotlin
val flow = yourApiCallReturningFlow()

flow.collect { element ->
   // process element here
}

// if we're here, the flow has completed
```

Any other terminal operator like `first()`, `toList()`, etc. will handle the flow's completion in some way (and may even cancel the flow early).

I'm not sure about what you're looking for here, but for example there is a terminal operator [count](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/count.html):

```kotlin
val flow = yourApiCallReturningFlow()

val hasAnyElement = flow.count() == 0
```

There is also [onEmpty](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-empty.html) that allows to emit some specific values instead of the empty flow.

I guess it depends on what you want to do when there *are* items in the flow.

Comment: Sorry but this is horribly misleading, I am giving you the benefit of the doubt but "if we're here, the flow has completed" is just straight up wrong. .collect does not return anything.

Comment: The fact that `.collect` does not return a meaningful value doesn't mean that `collect` never returns. As I said, it returns on flow completion. Of course, some flows never complete (e.g. `StateFlow` and `SharedFlow`), in which case the line after collect will never be executed. Could you please expand on why you think this is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [onEmpty](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-empty.html) method that will invoke an action if the flow completes without emitting any items.

It can also be used to emit a special value to the flow to indicate that it was empty. For example, if you have a flow of events you can emit an `EmptyDataEvent`.

Or you can just do whatever it is that you want to do inside this onEmpty lambda.

Highly related is also the [onCompletion](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-completion.html) method

Answer (score 1):

I resorted to

```kotlin
flow.take(1).count() == 0
```

This will wait only as long as it takes for the Flow to emit one element, or end without emitting any elements.

The resulting count will either be `0` or `1`. If it is `0`, then the Flow is empty. If it is `1` then the Flow contains at least one element and so is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
flow.firstOrNull().isNullOrEmpty()
```

- toList() is expansive operator
- first handle by exception